# Simple string property won't seem to bind in XAML GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a `Page` where I want to display a `string` property in a `Label`.
This is my code, but nothing will appear in the label.

This is my `.xaml`

```
<Page x:Class="MyProject.PageOne"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
          mc:Ignorable="d" 
          d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
        Title="PageOne"
          Name="pageOne>
    <Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
 <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding ElementName=pageOne, Path=aStr}" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="43" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,00,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
</Grid>

</Page>
```

And this is my `.cs` code

```
    public partial class PageOne: Page, IPageInterface
    {
       public String aStr{get;set;}
       public PageOne()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

            }
       public void Start()
         {
            aStr = "Test";

        }

    }
```

Comment: you forgot to set the datacontext

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've read about it several times, but can't figure out how I would set it properly in this case.

Comment: i never used the `page` object before but on the loaded event which i assume it might be the `void Start()`. You simply need to tell the page to have itself as context so in the method at the beginning adding `this.datacontext = this` should fix it. If you come from a winform background simply see datacontext as a kind of datasource.

Comment: @Franck Thank you. Although it did not change anything. I tried `<Page DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">` alternatively, but without success.

Comment: there is a `loaded` event on the page object if you use that it works. But i am checking and where is your implementation of `INotifyPropertyChange` did you remove from the example or it's plainly not there. And binding will be `{Binding aStr}`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing really wrong with the code you posted, in terms of the problem you describe, is that you have not implemented some way for property change notifications to occur. Because the `aStr` property is not set to the new value until after the `Label` content has been initially set, without a way to receive notification, the framework has no way to know it needs to update the `Label` content.

In WPF the two main ways this is typically done (indeed, AFAIK the only two fully supported ways) are to create `DependencyProperty` instances, or to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Either will work fine.

Here is an example of how your code should look with `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented:

```
public partial class PageOne : Page, IPageInterface, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _astr;
    public String aStr
    {
        get { return _astr; }
        set { _astr = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        aStr = "Test";
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Implementing the interface involves a couple of simple steps:

1. Declare the event named `PropertyChanged`
2. Any time a property is changed, raise that event, passing the name of the property that's changing.

Note that to do this, you can't use auto-implemented properties. You need to implement each property yourself, with a backing field, and a call to a method that will raise the property.

.NET offers the convenient `[CallerMemberName]` attribute, which I show here. So in the setter method for your `aStr` property, after setting the backing field's value, you simply call the method without any parameters, and the runtime automatically fills in the correct property name for you.

Now, the code you posted has some other problems as well, in the XAML. First it won't compile because you left out a `"` character, and because you've got an extra `</Grid>` closing tag.

One other possible problem, though it's not possible to know for sure since we are missing the full context of how you display this `Page` object, is that the text's color is white. If you're putting the `Label` instance on a white background, then of course you won't be able to see the text, even if it were set correctly.

I note that commenter Franck has suggested that you should set the `DataContext`. The truth is, given the code you posted this is actually not necessary, and doing so wouldn't actually fix the problem you are having.

But if you do fix the underlying notification issue, then his suggestions are an *alternative* way that you can achieve the binding. By setting the `DataContext` to the object containing the property (here, your `PageOne` class), then when you are binding you can just specify the property name alone, without having to include the `ElementName` at all, and without having to use the `Path=` with the property name. You may find this technique more convenient, at least some of the time.

In the future, please take the time to provide [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. You are more likely to get an answer that way, and you will ensure that any answer you do get is as good as it can be.